# digitsAfterDecimal is not working for x axis hover label in dygraph

Tags: dygraphs

How can I assign digitsAfterDecimal: 0 to the x axis hover label? I tried:

```
axes: {
  x: {
    digitsAfterDecimal: 0
  }
}
```

in the chart options, but it's not working.